# How to load Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having trouble loading the Dplyr package. I manage to install it using install.packages() but when I try to load it using library I get this error message

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): namespace ‘lifecycle’ 0.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
```

Comment: Fully close R/Rstudio, reopen it and run `install.packages("lifecycle")`. Does it still give an error after that?

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you!